# Reuse StackPanel UI in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, reusability, stackpanel

I have multiple StackPanels in my UI.

```
<StackPanel>
          <Button>Button 1</Button>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
          <TextBlock Style= Margin="3,0,0,0" x:Name="Name" ../>
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel>
          <TextBox Margin="3,0,0,0" x:Name="Number" Width="35".. />
</StackPanel>
```

I want to use the button and textblock in one dialog and textblock and textbox in other. How do I do that?

Comment: Don't you put the first two stack panels in one dialog and the third in the second dialog? I think I'm missing what the question.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom control using the stackpanels with specific dependency properties which allow for the transfer of meta data (such as titles and other items) and actual data from the user to flow back and forth. Within it, utilize a content presenter [Content Presenter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentpresenter.aspx) to allow for unique content depending on the situation.

See [How To Create A Custom Control](http://wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html) to get started.